# What does the @ symbol mean in a Django URL?

Tags: django

In urls.py there is a line:

```
path('profile/view/@<username>/', main.views.foo.profile, name='fooprofile'),
```

What does the @ mean in `@<username>` ?

Where can I find this in the Django documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the [*at sign* `@` [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign), it has no special meaning, the same symbol is used in the URL. It is used such that people can visit:

```
/profile/view/@duke/
```

for example. This is often done to mimick the syntax of twitter for example.

Comment: OK so it doesn't have special meaning ... it's literally an @ in the URL?